# Android vs other mobiles

Tags: android

1.How to upgrade latest version of android os on android phones?

2.Is it possible to upload android applications to other mobiles?

Thanks for ur precious time!..

Comment: Not sure, but perhaps this question should be made ​​elsewhere like http://android.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: You cannot upgrade your OS version unless and until your mobile company provides an upgraded version of OS for that mobile model.

2: You cannot upload your application to other mobile.

Comment: If you use a free version of android, maybe you can update manually, right?.

Comment: First it's not possible to upload android applications to other mobiles, that's because Android apps generate *.apk file which is not compatible with other OS.

Second Some device "Windows Phone devices" like can embed Android Os ,thus you can Run Android Apps: Look at youtube you can find some video taliking about it.

Finally You can upgrade your OS version With two approach: 

 1. your mobile company provides an upgraded version of OS for that mobile model, and this is the secure way
 2. you can use some tools: Root your device, Download Custom ROMs, hack tools like Odin for Samsung.

Comment: @K_Anas thanks for your valuable comment. Actually I didn't have any idea about Odin. So thanks a lot for that.

Answer (score 0):

*Is it possible to upload android applications to other mobiles?*

No, it's not possible as Android apps generate **.apk* file which is not compatible with other OS.